# How does the MFC framework get the handle of the global Application object?

Tags: mfc

In the past few days I have one question:

In MFC, we create an application object derived from `CWinApp`. We create this object globally. So the MFC framework will use this object to start the application.

But I don’t know how the frame work comes to know about my global object.

Please explain me the internal mechanism whereby MFC learns about the application object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging the sample MFC application I learned how the framework knows about the application object.

The application object is global and inherited from `CWinApp`. Since the object is global this object is constructed before `WinMain` is called. While constructing the derived object the `CWinApp` class constructer is called; at this time framework captures the handle:

```
pModuleState->m_pCurrentWinApp = this;
```

The above line is copied from the MFC `CWinApp::CWinApp(LPCTSTR lpszAppName)` constructor.
If you want further details then go to the definition and declaration of the class `CWinApp`.

Comment: but initializing with this, when this(CWinApp dervied class object pointer) is not yet created as we are still in base class(CWinApp) constructor, how is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362kaah4.aspx):

> Each application that uses the
>   Microsoft Foundation classes can only
>   contain one object derived from
>   CWinApp. This object is constructed
>   when other C++ global objects are
>   constructed and is already available
>   when Windows calls the WinMain
>   function, which is supplied by the
>   Microsoft Foundation Class Library.
>   Declare your derived CWinApp object at
>   the global level.

Basically because your CWinApp object is a global variable, by the time the application gets to WinMain it has already instantiated your CWinApp object. And because there can be only one CWinApp object, it knows that this is the one.